# Jupyter Notebook theme changed my version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel, jupyter-console

I just changed my theme in jupyter notebook. However even though it's showing python 3. I input() does not work. Only raw_input().

Has anyone come across this before? It does say Python 3 in the top right.

I changed the theme back and still the same problem...

Comment: Try checking python version using `sys.version_info` value.

Answer (score 0):

You should install [ipykernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html) to manage multiple version of Python in Jupyter Notebook. Alternatively you can use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)